# how to use Element.status(); in Raphael.js

Tags: raphael

the documentation is too breif.
can anyone knowa about how to use Element.status() in Raphael.js?
very appreciate if you can give a demo.

Comment: Well, show us what you have tried until now, and try adding little more details to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Element.status shows the current animation applied to an element OR you can set the status on a particular animation.

Think of an animation interpolating between 0 and 1. So half way through an animation, it would have a value of 0.5. This is applied to whatever attribute is being animated. (So if animating x from 0 to 100 half way through, status will be 0.5 and x will be 50, not accounting for any easing applied like bounce).

So lets suppose instead of creating a nice smooth interpolation between attributes, we want to make an element move in 10 discrete steps. We can set the status each time of an animation manually. Example.

```
var raphAnimation = Raphael.animation( { x: 100, y: 100 }, 1000);
rect.status( raphAnimation, 0.5 )
```

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ff93tuz4/1/)

```
var rect = paper.rect(10, 20, 300, 200);

var raphAnimation = Raphael.animation( { x: 100, y: 100 }, 1000);

for( var c = 1; c <= 10; c++ ) {
    (function() {
      var step = c
      setTimeout( function() { 
        rect.status( raphAnimation, 0.1 * step )
      }, step * 200)
    })();
}
```

Note: If you repeat using the status set command, I think it will take the animation as fresh. So suppose the animation is from 0->100 and you set status to be 0.5 it will go half way. Now suppose you do the same and call it again with 0.5, it will now be 0.5 of the 'remainder' as it now only has half the distance to traverse.

Comment: thanks a lot Lan. it looks silmilar to keyframes in CSS3 animation. but keyframes is used to interpolate multiple animations in one loop, while status() is used to interpolate multiple steps in one animation course. right?

Comment: Sort of, you don't need to set multiple steps, that was just my example. You could just set it to be 0.5 to see where your normal animation would be half way through. Or maybe you could add a slider which varies the status between 0-1 and then you as you drag the slider the animation moves that far as well. Just a possible idea that may make sense to explain it more.

Comment: However, having said that, I'm not sure that it's not a bit buggy, it never seems to reduce if I set the status to a smaller value, only increase (was thinking you would be able to reverse an animation, but not sure I can using that).

Comment: Yes, I think it seems to animate an increase in percentage. So if you give it 0.5 it will animate half way, but then if you set it to 0.75, I guess it thinks now it has to animate only from 0.5 of x to 1 (instead of 0 to 1) so I will set myself to be 0.75 of (0.5->1). So that may be correct I suppose, if not counter intuitive.